# crear una división entre un campo input y un campo select - reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router-dom

No he podido lograr crear una división entre un campo input y un campo select.
El algoritmo lo que hace es cuando coloco un numero en el input1 me genera en el select los divisores de dicho numero **ahora lo que necesito es que me divida lo que hay en el input1 con el valor que seleccione en el select en otro input nuevo** 
He intentado de varias formas pero no he podido lograr la división de estos dos campos el input uno con el select

```js
import { useState } from 'react'


export default function Pruebas() {

  const [number, setNumber] = useState({input: 0, two: 0})
  const [division, setDivision] = useState()

  const [input, setInput] = useState()
    const [values, setValues] = useState([])

    const handleClick = event => {
        event.preventDefault()
        setValues([+input, ...values])
    }


  const useEffect1= ()=>{
    const { input, two} = number
    setDivision(Number(input) / Number(two))
  }

  const handleInput = (event) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target
    setNumber({...number, [name]: value})
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input placeholder='Ingrese divisor' value={input} onChange={event => setInput(event.target.value)} />
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Agregar divisor</button>

      
      <br /><br />

      <select name='two' class='form-control'>
                <option value='no' selected>
                    Select
                </option>
                {values.map((item, index) => (
                    <option key={index} value={item}>
                        {item - 1}
                    </option>
                ))}
            </select>
      
      <br />
      
      <button onClick={useEffect1}>dividir</button>
      <input value={division}  placeholder="Resultado división" readOnly/>

     
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Le faltarían algunos cambios a tu código.

Primero, dentro de la función `useEffect1`, no estás trayendo los datos del primer input correctamente. Los datos de ahí ya estaban justamente en el estado `input`.

Después, yo no haría la división dentro del `setDivision()`.

Más bien realizaría la división afuera y el resultado sería lo que setearía.

```
const useEffect1 = () => {
    const { two } = number;
    let inputValue = parseInt(input);
    let twoValue = parseInt(two);
    let result = inputValue / twoValue;
    setDivision(result);
  };
```

El otro cambio que haría sería la forma de capturar los datos del select.

Se le puede agregar un evento `onChange` y llamar a la función `handleInput`

```
<select name="two" class="form-control" onChange={handleInput}>
```

De esa forma recuperamos los datos del `<select>` y los guardamos en el estado.

Haciendo todos esos cambios, todo el código quedaría así:

```
import { useState } from 'react'


export default function Pruebas() {

  const [number, setNumber] = useState({input: 0, two: 0})
  const [division, setDivision] = useState()

  const [input, setInput] = useState()
    const [values, setValues] = useState([])

    const handleClick = event => {
        event.preventDefault()
        console.log(+input)
        console.log(input)
        setValues([+input, ...values])
    }


  const useEffect1= ()=>{
    const { two } = number
    let inputValue = parseInt(input)
    let twoValue = parseInt(two)
    let result = inputValue / twoValue
    setDivision(result)
  }

  const handleInput = (event) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target
    console.log(event.target)
    console.log(name)
    console.log(value)
    setNumber({...number, [name]: value})
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input placeholder='Ingrese divisor' value={input} onChange={event => setInput(event.target.value)} />
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Agregar divisor</button>

      
      <br /><br />

      <select name='two' class='form-control' onChange={handleInput}>
                <option value='no' selected>
                    Select
                </option>
                {values.map((item, index) => (
                    <option key={index} value={item - 1}>
                        {item - 1}
                    </option>
                ))}
            </select>
      
      <br />
      
      <button onClick={useEffect1}>dividir</button>
      <input value={division}  placeholder="Resultado división" readOnly/>

     
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit new]

Puedes probarlo en *SandBox* y verificar si hace lo que estabas buscando.

PD: Te recomiendo que elijas nombres un poco más intuitivos para tus funciones y objetos. Los nombres `useEffect1` y también `input` son muy genéricos y no describen muy bien el propósito para lo que se usan.

Comment: Muchas gracias me sirvo la división.

Comment: Genial. No olvides marcar una respuesta como "aceptada" si realmente te sirvió, [aquí se explica cómo hacerlo](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/427/c%C3%B3mo-funciona-la-aceptaci%C3%B3n-de-respuestas). Hacer eso ayuda a otras personas que tengan tu mismo problema a reconocer una respuesta útil .